# How to use views with a couchDB based app and a one-DB-per-user pattern?

Tags: database, view, couchdb, pouchdb

I'm new to CouchDB and I'm trying to develop an Ionic App using CouchDB/PouchDB to benefit from online/offline usability.
In a first version of the DB, I used views defined in the database to query relevant data. Using the Josh Morony's tutorials ([Multi users app tutorial](https://www.joshmorony.com/part-2-creating-a-multiple-user-app-with-ionic-2-pouchdb-couchdb/)), I added signup and login features, and I implemented an architecture with one db per user. I don't have any server side code except for authentication of users. But with one db per user I cannot use views that I have defined in the previous architecture (one main database). What are the good practices to get one db per user and use queries by views?

Should I :

- Add views to each new DB, which means code duplication?
- Build a central database to store views? Can you give me examples to do that properly?
- Forget query by views and filter directly in client side code?
- Other proposal?

Thanks for reading.